# GridView Value Pass

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm added a template field and made it a button click event. Then I'm trying to sent the value to event method and want to some operation with that value. I wrote following code. It has no compilation error but when i click `Present` browser shows following message:

**Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.**

Code:

```
 <div>
                <asp:Panel ID="PanelAllEmployee" runat="server" Height="400px">
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewAllEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" style="position:absolute;left:219px; top:202px;" >
                      <Columns>
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailID" HeaderText="Email ID" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" />
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Present">
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Present" />
                              </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                      </Columns>
                  </asp:GridView>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"> </asp:Label>

               </asp:Panel>
              </div>
```

Event Method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
        string id = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Label1.Text = id;
    }
```

Please be kind to help me. I'm beginner. Elaborate answer is much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

`EnableEventValidation="false"` in the page directive in code-behind

for ex:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
```

EDIT: .aspx :

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
 OnClick = "Button1_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>'  Text="Present" />
```

cs code:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        string id = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();


    }
```

using **ButtonField** and an **OnRowCommand** Event

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 

    OnRowCommand = "OnRowCommand">

 <Columns>

  <asp:ButtonField CommandName = "ButtonField"  DataTextField = "CustomerID"

        ButtonType = "Button"/>

 </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{

    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[index]; 

}
```

Comment: After doing that error shows indicating `LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;` Error Message: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.**

Comment: 'LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender'; this is you are doing wrong there is nothing Like LinkButton in your .aspx code

Comment: Sorry. I don't have `LinkButton`. Could you please tell me then how could I get the value of this `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>'` command in `Button1_Click` event. Sorry again. thanks for reply. @Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: Your solution has no error but I'm not getting value of ` DataField="Id"`. if I use `<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>` I get index value but I need value of Column `<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />`. Is it possible. Sorry to bother you. I'm new. Having so much trouble  kept doing it. Thanks. @Ganesh_Devlekar